# how do i reference an image from my css in asp.net-mvc on a hosting provider

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, path

i have this inside my site.css file (in the COntent directory)

```
body { width: 100%; background: #e7e6de url("/content/images/back-page1.png") repeat-x; font: normal 13px arial, sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #4c4c4c; }
```

it works fine when i test it locally but it doesn't work when i upload the site to the hosting provider.

the issue is around the url of the background image.  i assume its some path issue.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the URL relative to the css file.

If your css file is located under `content/style`

Then your url should be `../image/back-page1.png`